# Laravel's Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached

Tags: json, laravel, api

I'm calling an API which gives a nested mixture of JSON, STDClass, and Arrays. One of my main concerns was trying to take out specific data out of it which has been solved. The point is that the code worked until I tried to use Laravel blade. After creating a layout called master.layout.php, and creating a section called 'content' which takes the codes inside the  tag, It stopped working and kept giving me "Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached" error.

There were some solutions in Stackoverflow that I tried and some tricks to even bypass it by changing the xdebug config in PHP.ini file. but unfortunately, none of them worked for me. One the members said "it's better to take a look at the structure of your code instead of trying to bypass it so I did. From what I figured out, I feel like json_decode() function keep recursing since its a recursive function. I tried to set the depth for it but it didn't work as well. I'd be glad if someone guides me about the ways to fix this issue.
Here is the code:

price.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
    @php
        $btc = new \App\Http\Controllers\CoinsController();
        $parameters = [
            'start' => '1',
            'limit' => '1',
        ];
        $query = http_build_query($parameters);

        $result = $btc->apiGet('https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'."?".$query);
        $price = json_decode($result['response'])->data[0]->quote->USD->price;
    @endphp
    <h1>Bitcoin Price Live</h1>
    <h2>{{"Current Price of Bitcoin: ". $price}}</h2>

@stop
```

CoinsController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CoinsController extends Controller
{


    function apiGet($url)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                // Set Here Your Requesred Headers
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip',
                'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',


            ),
        )
        );

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            json_decode($response);
        }
        return view('index.price', compact('response'));
    }
}
```

Comment: change ```@stop
``` to ```@endsection```

Comment: @J. Doe I’ll give it a try in a few mins, but may I ask whats the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't really be instantiating the controller within the blade template.

The issue is that you are essentially causing infinite loop.

Within your controller you are loading your blade view. Then within your blade view you are creating a new instance of the controller and running the method again. That method then returns the same view and so the process starts again. This will then keep going on and on and on until PHP eventually hit's a limit - and that is the issue here.

Instead you should have one controller that returns the view. You could then have a separate class that you instantiate which just returns you the value you are after as a string. That way you are not reloading the controller and getting caught in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you so much that was the only point I didn't think about :)